# React Native Make View "Hug" the Top of the Keyboard

Tags: javascript, react-native

Let's say I have a view that is positioned absolute at the bottom of the screen. This view contains a text input. When the text input is focused, I want the bottom of the view to touch the top of the keyboard.

I've been messing around with KeyboardAvoidingView, but the keyboard keeps going over my view. Is it not possible to make this work with position absolute?

What other method can I try? Thanks!

Comment: it is possible use `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` if your app is not full screen

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Few days ago I have the same problem (although I have a complex view with TextInput as a child) and wanted not only the TextInput to be focused but the whole view to be "attached" to the keyboard. What's finally is working for me is the following code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.paddingInput = new Animated.Value(0);
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.keyboardWillShowSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', this.keyboardWillShow);
    this.keyboardWillHideSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this.keyboardWillHide);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardWillShowSub.remove();
    this.keyboardWillHideSub.remove();
}

keyboardWillShow = (event) => {
    Animated.timing(this.paddingInput, {
        duration: event.duration,
        toValue: 60,
    }).start();
};

keyboardWillHide = (event) => {
    Animated.timing(this.paddingInput, {
        duration: event.duration,
        toValue: 0,
    }).start();
};

render() {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                [...]
                <Animated.View style={{ marginBottom: this.paddingInput }}>
                    <TextTranslateInput />
                </Animated.View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
```

where [..] you have other views.

Comment: I am happy to hear that :)

Comment: Can confirm, this is a really slick solution.  Thanks for taking the time to post this!

Comment: Thanks for this! Just an FYI to others building for Android, there are some restrictions to using keyboardWillShow vs keyboardDidShow. If you are building for  Android, be sure to be aware of them: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard

Comment: If you're lazy to read docs, use @hackman validation.

Answer (score 8):

Custom hook:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Animated, Keyboard, KeyboardEvent } from 'react-native';

export const useKeyboardHeight = () => {
  const keyboardHeight = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardWillShow = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      Animated.timing(keyboardHeight, {
        duration: e.duration,
        toValue: e.endCoordinates.height,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    };

    const keyboardWillHide = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      Animated.timing(keyboardHeight, {
        duration: e.duration,
        toValue: 0,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    };

    const keyboardWillShowSub = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardWillShow',
      keyboardWillShow
    );
    const keyboardWillHideSub = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardWillHide',
      keyboardWillHide
    );

    return () => {
      keyboardWillHideSub.remove();
      keyboardWillShowSub.remove();
    };
  }, [keyboardHeight]);

  return keyboardHeight;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

@jazzdle example works great! Thank you for that!
 Just one addition - in `keyboardWillShow` method, one can add `event.endCoordinates.height` so paddingBottom is exact height as keyboard.

```
    keyboardWillShow = (event) => {
    Animated.timing(this.paddingInput, {
        duration: event.duration,
        toValue: event.endCoordinates.height,
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: If you do that you have to remove behavior='padding' from the KeyboardAvoidingView

Comment: It is not required to use KeyboardAvoidingView. You can have a view that is position absolutely and just modify/animate its bottom value.

Answer (score 4):

React Native now supports an `InputAccessoryView` which can be used for exactly this purpose - even for anchored `TextInput`s.

Here's a specific example: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/rn-tester/js/examples/InputAccessoryView/InputAccessoryViewExample.js

Answer (score 2):

Using Functional Component. This works for both iOS and Android

```
useEffect(() => {
const keyboardVisibleListener = Keyboard.addListener(
  Platform.OS === "ios" ? "keyboardWillShow" : "keyboardDidShow",
  handleKeyboardVisible
);
const keyboardHiddenListener = Keyboard.addListener(
  Platform.OS === "ios" ? "keyboardWillHide" : "keyboardDidHide",
  handleKeyboardHidden
);

return () => {
  keyboardHiddenListener.remove();
  keyboardVisibleListener.remove();
};}, []);


const handleKeyboardVisible = (event) => {
Animated.timing(paddingInput, {
  duration: event.duration,
  toValue: 60,
  useNativeDriver: false,
});};

 const handleKeyboardHidden = (event: any) => {
Animated.timing(paddingInput, {
  duration: event.duration,
  toValue: 0,
  useNativeDriver: false,
});};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to bottom position the element. Here's simple example -

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.top}/>
        <View style={styles.bottom}>
          <View style={styles.input}>
            <TextInput/>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  top: {
    flex: .8,
  },
  bottom: {
    flex: .2,
  },
  input: {
    width: 200,
  },
});
```