# React Native Align button on top of keyboard for all devices

Tags: typescript, react-native

I need to align a button, which is not at the bottom of the screen by design, to be in the middle of the screen. However, it should align to be on top of the keyboard for all devices.

If you check this screenshot :

[image]

For some devices, I managed to achieve this alignment, but on others, it's not perfectly aligned.

[image]

how can I manage this to work in all?

this is what I did so far :

```
<Padding paddingVertical={isKeyboardOpen ? Spacing.unit : Spacing.small}>
<Button
      variant="solid"
      label='Next'
      style={styles.submitBtn}
    />

</Padding>
```

And isKeyboardOpen is just a method which will create a listner based on the platform return true if keyboard is open :

```
 Keyboard.addListener(
  Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'keyboardWillShow' : 'keyboardDidShow',
  true 
 );
```

And submitBrn css class is :

```
submitBtn: {
  margin: Spacing.base,
},
```

Comment: Use keyboard avoiding view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689265/react-native-make-view-hug-the-top-of-the-keyboard might help :)

Answer (score 21):

First import this packages

```
import {
  Button,
  ScrollView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
```

Render method

```
 <KeyboardAvoidingView
  {...(Platform.OS === 'ios' ? { behavior: 'padding' } : {})}
  style={styles.container}>
  <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
    <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Tap here" />
  </ScrollView>
  <Button title="Next" />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

This are the styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  scrollView: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  input: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#dbdbdb',
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

Make sure the button is outside the scrollview.

> NOTE: You may need to adjust the offset prop of `KeyboardAvoidingView` if the keyboard has got autocomplete enabled.

[Stick button at the bottom of the screen demo](https://snack.expo.io/@raajnadar/sticky-button-with-keyboard-avoiding-view)

Comment: not really, I already went through KeyboardAvoidingView, but my case is different, keyboards in different platforms ( ios, android ) and different devices have different sizes, and my button by design it must located in middle of screen before textbox is focused, and when is focused then it should be stuck on top of the keyboard for all platforms and devices. in your example button is at bottom of screen and there are no need to adjust the button.

Comment: It happend when keyboard show up and scroll on input

Comment: Does this ONLY work on Android for anyone else?

Comment: No, It works for both android & ios. I will check again with the latest version.

Comment: @GrantSingleton thanks for catching the bug, in the latest version we don't need a behaviour prop for android.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is still looking for a solution to this I am posting a working example from October 2021 along with the react native documentation. This example is for a text input that when focused has a button labeled 'Scanner' above the keyboard. React native documentation refers to what we are creating here as a 'toolbar'.

Please see this for further details https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/inputaccessoryview

```
import {
  Button,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  InputAccessoryView,
  Text,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { BarCodeScanner } from "expo-barcode-scanner";
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";

function CreateSearchBar() {
  const inputAccessoryViewID = "uniqueID";
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [showScanner, setShowScanner] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
  }, []);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      // Do something when the screen is focused
      return () => {
        // Do something when the screen is unfocused
        // Useful for cleanup functions
        setShowScanner(false);
      };
    }, [])
  );

  onChangeSearch = (search) => {};

  setScannerShow = (show) => {
    setShowScanner(show);
  };

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    setShowScanner(false);
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Requesting for camera permission</Text>;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  if (showScanner) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.scanner}>
        <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
        />
        {scanned && (
          <Button
            title={"Tap to Scan Again"}
            onPress={() => setScanned(false)}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ScrollView keyboardDismissMode="interactive">
        <View style={styles.input}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="magnify" size={24} color="black" />
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
            inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID}
            placeholder="Find items or offers"
          />
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="barcode"
            size={30}
            color="black"
            onPress={() => setScannerShow(true)}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <InputAccessoryView nativeID={inputAccessoryViewID}>
        <Button onPress={() => setScannerShow(true)} title="Scanner" />
      </InputAccessoryView>
    </>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  scanner: {
    height: "50%",
  },
});

export default CreateSearchBar;
```

Comment: Be aware that, as stated in the documentation, InputAccessoryView is an iOS only feature.

Answer (score -2):

YOu can use react native modal

```
 <KeyboardAvoidingView
    keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS == "ios" ? 10 : 0}
    behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"} style={{ flex: 1         }} >
    <Modal>

       <ScrollView>  
      <Content><-------Your content------></Content>
       </ScrollView>  

      <BottomButton   />
    </Modal>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```