# How to stick the comment input box on top of keyboard

Tags: react-native

For my app, i added a comment text input box component . But it sticks to the post, and can be scrolled up and down along with the list of posted comments.

I want to make this text input box float on top of keyboard like the facebook new comment inout box.

Any pointers how to achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code about what you tried so far?

Comment: it will help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456327/react-native-align-button-on-top-of-keyboard-for-all-devices`

Comment: @HardikVirani, Thanks it worked perfectly.

Comment: use keyboard avoiding view for this