# KeyboardAvoidingView not working on iOS with react navigation header and material bottom tabs?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-navigation

*Update for 2023*

The bug is back. [I reported it here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/11244).

I tested all known fixes and they do not work currently.

Follow these simple steps to reproduce:

- `npx expo init <yourReproNameHere>`
- `Use the "tabs" template
- Fill any of the two screens with anything (I used `<Button/>`)
- Add a `<TextInput>` at the end of the screen
- --> The keyboard hides the `<TextInput>` and `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` will not fix it

This old image still shows the bug
[image: Issue on iOS]

[[Old Bug which is solved]](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3971)

Answer (score 3):

I create a wrapping component like this and pass the offset from the screen so that it gets the current context.

```
import React from 'react'

import { ViewStyle } from 'react-native'

import { KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, ScrollView } from 'react-native'

type Props = {
    children: any
    keyboardVerticalOffset?: number
    contentContainerStyle?: ViewStyle
}

export default function KeyboardWrapper({
    children,
    keyboardVerticalOffset,
    ...rest
}: Props): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            keyboardVerticalOffset={keyboardVerticalOffset}
            {...(Platform.OS === 'ios' ? { behavior: 'padding' } : {})}>
            <ScrollView
                bounces={false}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                {...rest}>
                {children}
            </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
}
```

Usage in the screen

If you have any sticky elements like topbar or bottom bar you need to add the height so that the keyboard adds the offset correctly.

```
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements'

const height = useHeaderHeight()

<KeyboardWrapper
    keyboardVerticalOffset={height}
    contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
    // ... your elements
</KeyboardWrapper>
```

This is a working demo https://snack.expo.dev/@raajnadar/fix-keyboardavoidingview-not-working

Comment: ``If you have any sticky elements like topbar or bottom bar you need to add the height so that the keyboard adds the offset correctly.``

That's what I thought, but how do I get those heights? Did you see my simple Snack? Could you fix that case?https://snack.expo.dev/@tomwaitforitmy/keyboardavoidingview

Comment: I tried passing headerHeight from the navigation screen to the component in my Snack. Nothing changes. I think I would need something like `useMaterialBottomTabsHeight` which does not exist.

Comment: Please try this minimal example https://snack.expo.dev/@raajnadar/fix-keyboardavoidingview-not-working

Comment: Not working for me on IOS. Edit field is behind the keyboard. I cannot upload the screenshot here, but I am sure your Snack looks the same if you run it on IOS.

Comment: See screen shot here: https://imgur.com/a/WwC789A

Comment: If I am not wrong you want the input to be sticky at the bottom right even without a keyboard correct?

Comment: I want the edit field to not be behind the keyboard. It should move up, if the keyboard opens -> KeyboardAvoidingView.

Comment: Can you please check the snack now, it should work now? https://snack.expo.dev/@raajnadar/fix-keyboardavoidingview-not-working

Comment: No, not even on iOS simulator of expo snacks https://imgur.com/a/7ykPFY1

Comment: And my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54456543/5519872

Comment: You removed the whole content of the screen. That's not my issue anymore. Furthermore, the edit field is sticky on the top. I want the edit field be at the button of the scroll bar content. In reality, I have many edit fields in my scroll bar and almost all of them are hidden by the Keyboard (only the very top fields like yours). Not helpful for me I fear.

Comment: It seems the issue is due to the Flat list, I have an application in which I have a similar screen with many inputs, an app bar and a bottom bar, I am using the above wrapper and it works very well.

Comment: I tried to exchange FlatList with ScrollView. In fact, I am only using FlatList, because someone else suggested the issue is due to ScrollView. While the issue is related to anything "scrollable", it is not due to a specific list. Does your app use the Native-StackNavigator AND the Material-Bottom-Tabs both together? If yes, would it be possible for me to see your code base?

Comment: The issue lies with material bottom tabs, when I switched to bottom tabs it was solved, check the snack that I gave

Comment: That is true and works now. So confirmed you need material-bottoms-tabs.

Comment: The material bottom tab is from react-native-paper, I will report that to the team

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to add `64` to the `headerHeight`. Here is how I would solve this problem.

```js
const flatListRef = createRef()
const [data, setData] = useState()
const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();

<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
          keyboardVerticalOffset={headerHeight}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            ref={flatListRef}
            onContentSizeChange={() =>
              flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })
            }
            onLayout={() => flatListRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text style={{ flex: 1, paddingVertical: 20 }}>{item.id}</Text>
            )}
          />
          <View style={{ flex: 1, marginBottom: 40 }}>
            <TextInput
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#2E2E2E',
                width: '100%',
                borderRadius: 18,
                height: 36,
                paddingLeft: 10,
                paddingRight: 10,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
              }}
            />
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </View>
```

Here is a quick and dirty [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@pgrepds/keyboard-avoiding) which contains an header from a `StackNavigator`.

Comment: The main difference I see is that you use FlatList instead of ScrollView. Is that the cause of the bug or what exactly of your solution solves it?

Comment: The container of `TextInput` has a `flex: 1` property which pushes it to the bottom. I have removed the additional `64` offset, which is not necessary.

Comment: Your code example works stand alone. I could not make in my app so far however. That means there is something wrong still on my side. Just adding `flex: 1` and removing the 64 did not do the trick ...

Comment: Share your updated code please, then I could have a look.

Comment: Wow, that would be awesome: https://github.com/tomwaitforitmy/mangi-bevi/tree/DavidScholz and here is how it looks on my devices: https://photos.app.goo.gl/krydfhx6m3bDjvS18 - is the material bottom navigator the cause?

Comment: I found out that it is indeed material bottom tabs causing the issue.

Comment: I created a minimal snack if you are in the mood: https://snack.expo.dev/@tomwaitforitmy/keyboardavoidingview

Comment: Is this problem related to [this issue on github](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10151)? It seems like a general problem with bottom tabs.

Comment: Hard to answer for me. I will ask there.